# Mongoose Query documents with an array which contains at least one element of an array in the document.

Tags: mongoose, mongodb-query

Lets say I have the following documents in a collection:

```
{ _id: 1, numbers: [ 82, 85, 88 ] }
{ _id: 2, numbers: [ 75, 88, 89 ] }
{ _id: 3, numbers: [ 75, 90, 93 ] }
```

Would there be a way to query the documents such that given an array such as:

```
[75, 90, 91]
```

the result would contain:

```
{ _id: 2, numbers: [ 75, 88, 89 ],
  _id: 3, numbers: [ 75, 90, 93 ]}
```

since at least one of the elements in the given array was contained in the numbers arrays?

Comment: I cannot think of a single search phrase that does not point to [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) and yet fails to find a duplicate question. Though it would be an achievement to search google and not be pointed to that documentation page. But then I did find the duplicate. Yay! A reasonable search should really have landed you on the documentation though.